# Где я могу задать ключи для компиляции в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, компиляция, компилятор

Прочитал на хабре, что можно уменьшить время компиляции, за счет ключа параллельной компиляции /MP. В настройках не вижу таких пунктов. Поиск в гугле не дал результатов. Используется Visual Studio 2017.
UPD. В частности интересует C# под Windows Forms.

Comment: Зависит от типа проекта, уточните в вопросе.

Comment: Изменил. Видимо, я ошибочно полагал, что данная опция есть в настройках, и охватывает все компилируемые проекты студии.

Comment: `msbuild` можно заставить скомпилировать несколько несвязанных проектов, для этого необходимо задать ключ `/m`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Параметр /MP служит для ускорения компиляции **нативных** проектов (C++ или C), в C# проектах этот параметр не поддерживается, да и в целом не нужен.

Документация: [ссылка.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/mp-build-with-multiple-processes)

Comment: Спасибо, в статье не был указан язык, это меня и сбило с пути.